# VSTS Build failed when associated with Hockey App

Tags: uwp, azure-devops, hockeyapp

I am trying to associate my UWP App build with the Hockey App but it's getting failed.

Below are the configurations I have set:

For Build:

**MSBuild Arguments:**

> /p:AppxBundlePlatforms="$(BuildPlatform)"
>   /p:AppxPackageDir="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\AppxPackages\"
>   /p:AppxBundle=Always /p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=StoreUpload

For Hockey App:

**Binary Path:**

`$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\AppxPackages\UWPVSTSBuild_$(AppxVersion)_Test\UWPVSTSBuild_$(AppxVersion)_x86_x64_ARM.appxbundle`

Error that I am getting after build process:

```
Error: Not found binaryPath:   D:\a\1\a\AppxPackages\UWPVSTSBuild_$(AppxVersion)_Test\UWPVSTSBuild_$(AppxVersion)_x86_x64_ARM.appxbundle
```

Is there anything that I am missing in the parameter?

Comment: Do you have a variable named "AppxVersion" defined in the build definition? According to the logs, it was not expanded during the build.

Comment: Ohh, Actually I don't have "AppxVersion" variable declared? Can you please help me on how to set this variable taking version number as a dynamic value.

Comment: Got it, I added '"AppxVersion"' this variable in my build definition. Will update you once the build in completed.

Comment: Another question is that how do you configure your project to generate the output with name "UWPVSTSBuild_$(AppxVersion)_x86_x64_ARM.appxbundle", according to the settings in MSBuild agruments, you didn't set it. It would be helpful if you can share the build logs for msbuild step.

Comment: After adding "AppxVersion" my build got to succeed and I can see my package in the Hockey App. To answer your question, I have publish artifact with below configuration '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\AppxPackages'. Let me know if you still need more details.

Comment: If it works, then no more questions. :)